# Range partitioning tables with data in DB2 LUW

Tags: loops, db2, prepared-statement, partitioning

First of all my question will be, if there is a way of auto-generation partitions (like interval in Oracle for range partitioning) while inserting data into the partitioned table in DB2?

At the moment I have a schema with some hundreds of tables, which are not partitioned. And I suppose to partition them.
My steps will be:

- rename all the tables to OLD_table_name
- execute DDLs for those tables but already partitioned (by load_id column int data type)
- execute for all, insert into table_name select * from OLD_table_name

...and here it starts. 
(Of course the process must be automatically and I don't know which values contain load_id column + they will be all different for all the tables, otherwise it would be possible to generate simply alter statements and execute them).
Therefore I would go for cursor.

For the moment I have solution which is working but I don't like it:

```
BEGIN
FOR CL AS MYCURS INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR
    select distinct 'alter table '||tb_nm||' 
                    add partition PART_'||lpad(load_id,5,0)||' 
                    starting from '||load_id||' 
                    ending at '||load_id v_alt 
    from (
    select load_id,'Table_01' tb_nm from Table_01 
     union  
    select load_id ,'Table_02'from Table_02
     union
    ....
    /*I have generated this union statements for whole set of tables*/)
do 
   execute immediate v_alt;
end for;
end
```

Also, I have tried some more elegant (on my opinion) variant, but didn't sucseed:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE v_stmnt VARCHAR(1000); 
DECLARE v_check_val int;  
DECLARE v_prep_stmnt STATEMENT; 

for i as (select table_name 
            from sysibm.tables 
           where TABLE_SCHEMA ='shema_name'
         )
do 
    SET v_stmnt = 'set ? = (SELECT distinct(load_id) FROM '||table_name||')';
    PREPARE v_prep_stmnt FROM v_stmnt;
    /*and here I stuck. I assume there must be possibility to run next execute as well in loop, but 
    all my attempts were not succsesfull*/
    --EXECUTE v_prep_stmnt into v_check_val ;
end for;
END
```

Would highly appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

BEGIN
  DECLARE L_TABSCHEMA VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'SCHEMA_NAME';
  DECLARE L_COLNAME   VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'LOAD_ID';
  DECLARE L_VALUE     INT;
  DECLARE L_STMT      VARCHAR(1024);
  DECLARE SQLSTATE    CHAR(5);

  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;

  FOR I AS 
    SELECT TABNAME
    FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABSCHEMA = L_TABSCHEMA AND COLNAME = L_COLNAME
  DO
    PREPARE S1 FROM 'SELECT DISTINCT(' || L_COLNAME || ') FROM ' || L_TABSCHEMA || '."' || I.TABNAME ||'"';
    OPEN C1;
    L1: LOOP
      FETCH C1 INTO L_VALUE; 
      IF SQLSTATE<>'00000' THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
      SET L_STMT =
        'alter table ' || L_TABSCHEMA || '."' || I.TABNAME || '" '
      ||'add partition PART_' || lpad(L_VALUE, 5, 0) || ' starting from ' || L_VALUE || ' ending at ' || L_VALUE;
      --CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_STMT);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_STMT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE C1;
  END FOR;
END
@
```

Comment: Many thanks @Mark Barinstein ! 
This is exactly what I was aiming for. In my final version I have added only a very small detail: 
`PREPARE S1 FROM 'SELECT DISTINCT(' || L_COLNAME || ') FROM ' || L_TABSCHEMA || '."OLD_' || I.TABNAME ||'"';` as data currently is in OLD_table_name tables.
But with your solution I realized I am missing knowledge about preparing in DB2.